# Count Value with smaller than and Endswith condition

Tags: python

Problem:
Find unitcode that endswith '1001' in the .txt file and count this unit if anyone getting marks below 50. If yes, count. If no, give a value of 0

My code:

```
skipped_header = True
counters_unit_code = {}
with open("inp.txt") as csv_file:
  for line in csv_file:
    if skipped_header:
      skipped_header = False
      continue
    record = line.rstrip().split(':')
    unit_code = record[2].endswith('1001')
    min_mark = int(record[4])
    if unit_code not in counters_unit_code:
      counters_unit_code[unit_code]=0
    if min_mark < 50:
      counters_unit_code[unit_code] += 1

for unit_code in counters_unit_code:
  print(str(unit_code),counters_unit_code[unit_code])
```

My output:

```
False 1
True 3
```

Expected output:

```
engl1001 3
math1001 0
```

txt file (inp.txt):

```
Name:unikey:unitcode:year:mark
Joe Smith:jsmi3031:chem1101:2016:40
Oleg Catem:ocat3031:chem1101:2016:79
Joe Smith:jsmi3031:engl1001:2015:0
Joe Smith:jsmi3031:engl1001:2016:45
Tim Gold:tgol2145:engl1001:2016:46
Paula Dong:pdon1234:engl1001:2016:91
Joe Smith:jsmi3031:engl1001:2017:54
Oleg Catem:ocat3031:engl1001:2017:87
Oleg Catem:ocat3031:math1001:2016:95
Joe Smith:jsmi3031:math1001:2016:59
Paula Dong:pdon1234:math1001:2016:99
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unit_code = record[2].endswith('1001')`
This line gives you True or False and not substring.

for substring use

```
if record[2].endswith('1001'):
   unit_code = record[2][:-4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```py
unit_code = record[2].endswith('1001')
```

The `.endswith()` function returns a boolean value, which is why your output contains "True" and "False" instead of the unit codes.  I think you meant to extract the unit code, and test whether it ends with '1001'.  Something more like this:

```py
skipped_header = True
counters_unit_code = {}
with open("inp.txt") as csv_file:
  for line in csv_file:
    if skipped_header:
      skipped_header = False
      continue
    record = line.rstrip().split(':')
    unit_code = record[2]
      if unit_code.endswith('1001'):
        min_mark = int(record[4])
        if unit_code not in counters_unit_code:
          counters_unit_code[unit_code] = 0
        if min_mark < 50:
          counters_unit_code[unit_code] += 1

for unit_code in counters_unit_code:
  print(str(unit_code), counters_unit_code[unit_code])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
skipped_header = True
counters_unit_code = {}
with open("inp.txt") as csv_file:
  for line in csv_file:
    if skipped_header:
      skipped_header = False
      continue
    record = line.rstrip().split(':')
    unit_code = record[2]
    min_mark = int(record[4])
    if unicode.endswith('1001'):
      if unit_code not in counters_unit_code:
        counters_unit_code[unit_code]=0
      if min_mark < 50:
        counters_unit_code[unit_code] += 1

for unit_code in counters_unit_code:
  print(str(unit_code),counters_unit_code[unit_code])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant your expected value for eng1001 is 3 right?

The problem was your line

```
unit_code = record[2].endswith('1001')
```

endswith returns a boolean-value

This should do, what you are trying to achieve:

```
skipped_header = True
counters_unit_code = {}
unit_code = 0
with open("inp.txt") as csv_file:
    for line in csv_file:
        if skipped_header:
            skipped_header = False
            continue
        record = line.rstrip().split(':')
        if record[2].endswith('1001'):
            unit_code = record[2]
        min_mark = int(record[4])
        if unit_code not in counters_unit_code:
            counters_unit_code[unit_code] = 0
        if min_mark < 50:
            counters_unit_code[unit_code] += 1

for unit_code in counters_unit_code:
    print(str(unit_code), counters_unit_code[unit_code])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re` instead of basing it on `:`s

```
import re

pattern = r"(\w{4}1001):\d{4}:(\d+)"

with open("inp.txt") as csv_file:
    values = csv_file.read()
    subjects = {}
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, values):
        subject, score = match.groups()
        scores = subjects.setdefault(subject, [])
        if int(score) < 50:
            scores.append(score)

    for subject, scores in subjects.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(subject, len(scores)))

# Output
engl1001: 3
math1001: 0
```